# php json data not working

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've created an array using php which I've then json encoded

```
$json_array =  json_encode($newarray);
```

In my jquery, the encoded array seems to be formed OK (i think??) but when I try and use the json data - nothing happens? I'm expecting the textbox to autocomplete.

The funny thing is - it works if I use arraytxt2, but not arraytxt1 (the one created via json_encode).

Any ideas as to why arraytxt1 is not working?? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arraytxt1 = [{
        "equipmentid": "1",
        "equipmentmake": "Baxi"
    }, {
        "equipmentid": "2",
        "equipmentmake": "Baxi"
    }];

    var arraytxt2 = [{
        "id": "1",
        "label": "aa"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "label": "bb"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "label": "bbbb"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "label": "abab"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "label": "cab"
    }];

    $("#txt1").autocomplete({
        source: arraytxt1,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#txt2").val(ui.item.equipmentid);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It makes it much easier for you, and others, to understand.

Comment: Both arraytxt1 and arraytxt2 are valid JSON (jsonlint.com). Something must be amiss in the code you didn't provide. Do you see any errors in your developer console or is the value of #txt2 just not updating?

Comment: Is the data for arraytxt1 in this code just for example? or are you fetching the json data from php in the javascript? If the latter then you might need to convert the JSON string into the array format you have here.

Comment: Sorry @Rory McCrossan first time posting and simply copied and pasted the code. Apologies.

Comment: Hi @spaniol6 yes the  second array was simply to test. The fields in the first array are coming from the database via php then encoded. Thanks for your input. Appreciate it. Chris

Answer (score 1):

The correct keys for autocomplete's array objects are `label` and `value`. The value property might not be needed in your case.

https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Try:

```
var arraytxt1 = [{
    "equipmentid": "1",
    "label": "Baxi"
}, {
    "equipmentid": "2",
    "label": "Baxi"
}];
```

Comment: Thanks @toster-cx the value and label labels are coming from database via php and encoded. I'll try changing the second array for testing purposes and see if I can still get it work? Thanks indeed for your input. Chris

Comment: Got it sorted! Thanks @toster-cx, you put me on the right track. I've changed the array to id and label. Thanks to everyone who helped. Appreciated